# Firefox 4, 5 and 6 are slow and freezing, consuming 400MB RAM

Tags: windows-7, firefox, memory, upgrade, updates

I'm on Windows 7. Since I upgraded to Firefox 4, I noticed that it became extremely slow. I even tried to upgrade to 6 and 5 and still it's slow. Sometimes it consumes 400 MB of RAM!

What can I do? Is there a fix?

Comment: 400MB isn't that much for a browser these days. What is your hardware actually?

Comment: Have you tried to throw away (at least temporarily) your user profile?

Comment: What plugins did you add?  Most of the slowdowns I've seen in Firefox are due to plugins that are slow or having problems.

Comment: Pfft, when I have a couple dozen tabs open Firefox uses about 3GB of memory...